# C-makefile and external libraries

Tags: c, compilation

Where should I put -lm to include math.h library in my project?

```
@clear
@echo  
@echo Compiling  
@cc -c rpn.c   
@cc -c  stos.c   
@cc rpn.o stos.o  
@rm -f *.o  
@echo Compilation success
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Makefiles for `make`. It looks like a .bat file.

Comment: "Where should I put -lm to include math.h library in my project?" - nowhere, you `#include <math.h>` from the source file. And you put the `-lm` linker flag into the invocation of the linker in order to **link against** the math library.

Answer (score 2):

Functions from math.h are defined in `libm` library. To add a library, one should specify `-l<name>` parameter for the linker, where `<name>` is name of the library without the `lib` prefix. So just add `-lm` parameter to the linking command:

```
`cc rpn.o stos.o -lm`
```